# jQuery delete cookie doesn't delete when redirecting

Tags: c#, cookies

I have multiple cookies with the same name, domain and path, but different values. This is not by design - I am trying to fix this, but cannot delete them. I have tried multiple code variations. Here is one:

```
string[] cookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
HttpCookie cookie;
string cookieName;
string cookieValue;
for (int i = 0; i < cookies.Count(); i++)
{
  cookieName = Request.Cookies[i].Name;
  if (cookieName == "ASP.NET_SessionId")
  {
    //  Do not delete session cookie or we will be logged out
    continue;
  }

  cookieValue = Request.Cookies[i].Value;
  cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
  cookie.Value = "";
  cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

And here is another:

```
string[] cookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Count(); i++)
{
    if (Request.Cookies[i].Name == "ASP.NET_SessionId")
    {
        //  Do not delete session cookie or we will be logged out
        continue;
    }

    Request.Cookies[i].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
}
```

When I list the cookies in Request.Cookies, the  "deleted" cookies show up with an expiration date of yesterday, but there are other cookies that show up with an expiration date of 1/1/0001. These are the ones that just won't take a hint and take a hike.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: To logout a user you want to clear the authentication cookie for example calling FormsAuthentication.Signout() in you c# code.

Comment: are the case of the cookie correct for e.g. $.cookie("UserId", might be $.cookie("userid",

Comment: The cases are correct, but there appear to be multiple copies of several of the critical cookies. I have tried to delete ALL cookies, but they keep coming back.

Comment: Manipulating cookies both client side and server side can be a tricky undertaking depending on the order of your rendering and then postback.

Comment: @BobJones is there code in the site that is adding them back?

Comment: It turns out that some of the cookies are in different domains. This shows up in IE with the tool bar (F12) and View Cookies, but I haven't found any way yet to get this information myself. So what is happening is that I read a cookie that has multiple instances (same name, different domain), and since I cannot filter by domain, I get cookies that I don't want... and cannot delete. I finally logged into the offending domain and was able to delete them... but I still want to know how to do this in my code.

Comment: The domains in question are dev.domainname.com, test.domainname.com and domainname.com and the cookies for domainname.com show up in the Request.Cookies list for dev.domainname.com, but without the domain name. So how can I filter them to get just the cookies from the current domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the expire date a year into the past instead of 1 day?

Here is a post on the [deleting cookies](http://www.hackification.com/2009/01/25/how-to-delete-a-cookie-in-aspnet/). In his code he sets the date back 30 years.

Set the domain on the cookies.

```
  cookieValue = Request.Cookies[i].Value;
  cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
  cookie.Value = "";
  cookie.Domain = "dev.domain.com";
  cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: One day, one month, one year, one century - all in the past. Not the issue here. The problem is that I have multiple cookies with the same name and different domains, but they are showing up as being in the same domain.

Comment: @BobJones Are they sub domains? Cookies from different domains should not be visible. Are you trying to kill cookies in a child domain from a parent domain?

Comment: there is a domain hierarchy: dev.domain, test.domain and domain. When I read Request.Cookies in dev or test or domain, I only want to see the cookies for that domain, but instead, I am seeing multiple instances of each cookie, but without any associated domain name, so I cannot tell which cookie I am reading.

Comment: @BobJones Set the domain on the cookies. Then you will only see cookies from the current domain. The domain name can be driven by the configuration. In production is your domain www.domain.com, domain.com or can both be used?